# How to pass pointer to GLEW function to a template?

Tags: c++, templates, opengl

I'm trying to write a simple wrapper for OpenGL that holds buffers. Since there are many buffers, each with a specialized generate and delete function, I was hoping to use a template so that I can create these wrappers easily. The end goal is to have something like this:

```
gl::VBO v;
v.gen();
```

I have tried to do the following:

```
using TBuilder = void(*)(GLsizei, GLuint *);

template<std::size_t N, TBuilder TConstructor, TBuilder TFreer>
struct OGLWrapper{
    std::array<GLuint, N> data;
    void gen(){
        TConstructor(N, &data[0]);
    }
    ~OGLWrapper(){
        TFreer(N, &data[0]);
    }
};

using VBO = OGLWrapper<1, glGenBuffers, glDeleteBuffers>;
```

The problem is that `glGenBuffers` and `glDeleteBuffers` are not compile time constants. They are unusable until `glewInit()` is called. I was hoping there would be a way to delay lookup of these functions until a VBO is generated. It is entirely possible that templates cannot be used in this situation, but I am hoping there is a smart way of wrapping my OpenGL resources.

---

After reading the answers, I got as far as this:

```
using TBuilder = decltype(&glGenBuffers);
using TFreer = decltype(&glDeleteBuffers);

template<std::size_t N, TBuilder TCons, TFreer TDes>
struct OGLWrapper{
    std::array<GLuint, N> data;
    OGLWrapper():data{}{}
    void gen(){
        (*TCons)(N, &data[0]);
    }
    ~OGLWrapper(){
        (*TDes)(N, &data[0]);
    }
};

using VBO = OGLWrapper<1, &glGenBuffers, &glDeleteBuffers>;
using VAO = OGLWrapper<1, &glGenVertexArrays, &glDeleteVertexArrays>;
```

Which is nice, but I was hoping to remove the TBuilder and TFreer typedefs. My concern is generalization, since I am unsure of if other functions use these signatures. Is there a way to make the template deduce these types?

Comment: If it is not compile-time, it will never work as a template parameter - use a normal (run-time) parameter for the function.

Comment: Is there any way to have something similar to `using` so that I don't have to write the function parameters each time?

Answer (score 1):

```
using TBuilder = void(*)(GLsizei, GLuint *);

template<std::size_t N, TBuilder* TConstructor, TBuilder* TFreer>
struct OGLWrapper{
  std::array<GLuint, N> data;
  void gen(){
    (*TConstructor)(N, &data[0]);
  }
  ~OGLWrapper(){
    (*TFreer)(N, &data[0]);
  }
};

using VBO = OGLWrapper<1, &glGenBuffers, &glDeleteBuffers>;
```

live example

We store pointers to the function pointers.  The function pointers are only updated when you call `glewInit()`.  So if you use your VBO before that point, it will do UB, but what do you expect?

One thing you may have to be careful about is calling convention.  But so long as your `typedef` for the `TBuilder` is accurate, you will be good.

A final concern is that your destructor runs even if `gen` is not called.  Possibly you should run `gen` in the constructor of the class?  Or record if `gen` has been called with a `bool`.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about the function pointers - was just about to undo my edit.

Comment: The issue is that `glGenBuffers` is not necessarily a type of TBuilder. They are defined as `#define glGenBuffers GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewGenBuffers)`, and their internal types are all different. For example, `glGenBuffers` is `PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC` and `glDeleteBuffers` is `PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSPROC` and I can't convert between pointers to those types and TBuilder.

Comment: @user975989 that sounds like a completely different problem than what you describe in the OP?  From my readings of the source, the types are fixed, but different for the two cases.  So use a different types for the two cases?  Is it the problem that they are sometimes pointers, and sometimes not?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault for miscommunicating. Is there a way that I can deduce the type without having to type a typedef for each type?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses macros to construct the wrappers, but usage is macro-free:

```
#define CREATE_GLEW_WRAPPER(name, N, construct, freer) \
    struct name {                                      \
        std::array<GLuint, N> data;                    \
        void gen() {                                   \
            construct(N, &data[0]);                    \
        }                                              \
                                                       \
        ~name() {                                      \
            freer(N, &data[0]);                        \
        }                                              \
    };                                               

namespace gl {
    CREATE_GLEW_WRAPPER(VBO, 1, glGenBuffers, glDeleteBuffers)
}

#undef CREATE_GLEW_WRAPPER
```